# Applying a patch to Maven war overlay

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

We have a Maven war overlay project that currently adds a number of classes and resources files to the war. We also need to modify a number of files. Instead of copying the files into our project and doing the modifications there, we want to use the Maven patch plugin. However, since the war overlay seems to occur within one Maven build phase (package), there seems to be no way to apply the patches at the correct time.

Is there a simple solution to apply patches to a war file using Maven?